# Show One Marker Only in LineChart

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, charts, flutter-animation

I am using line series from syncfusion_flutter_charts and I want to show only one marker at one specific point in line series. How can I achieve that ? Currently LineSeries takes markerSettings as argument but it shows markers for all the points in LineSeries but I want to show marker for only one specific point in line series. How can I achieve that?
plugin link: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts

picture for reference: [image: ![markers on line graph]

I want to show only one marker instead of marker at every point.

Answer (score 0):

As official documentation of `syncfsion_flutter_charts`, there is no customization available for points for now. The only customization is for lines.

https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-charts/chart-types/stacked-line-100-chart?utm_source=pubdev&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=flutter-charts-pubdev

Answer (score 0):

The class SfCartesianChart has a method onMarkerRender.
It returns marker arguments for every point where the marker appears.

you can set up a specific condition in the method's body.
e.g:

```
void onMarkerRender(MarkerRenderArgs args) {
final point = args.pointIndex;
if (point == null) return;
if (chartData[point] == chartData.first) {
  args.markerWidth = 10;
  args.markerHeight = 10;
}
```

}

In this logic, every point which doesn't fit this condition will be hidden.